# Rest API Security Questions

Tags: rest, express, security, cors

I am writing a REST API using Express Js and I have some questions regarding security.

My first question is what information can hackers get from a request made from the client side. Can they figure out the request link? What about the body and headers? Is body more secure than parameters/vice versa?

My second question is if I implemented a CORS whitelist that only allowed origins that I wanted to access my API, would that prevent anyone else from hitting the API endpoints? Can people find ways around CORS?

Comment: You should use SSL, then in case of man in the middle attack, a domain name would be visible but other parts like path, params, body should be encrypted between client and server. Passwords should go through body.

Answer (score 1):

When a REST api is called from a browser client, *everything* should be treated as completely open. Anyone can read urls, headers, bodies, etc. There is no reasonable way around this, and you should design your system with this in mind.

CORS does not prevent someone from writing a script to call your API either. CORS does not *add* security, it takes it away by making it possible to call your API from browser applications on other domains. Not having CORS technically makes it harder to call your API in some contexts, and removes a potential security concern. The S in CORS stands for 'sharing', not 'security'.

Any security you need should be based on the server. For example, if you have data in your API that can only be read 1 user, then the server needs to make sure that a different user cannot read it. To do this, a user needs to authenticate itself.

Comment: That makes sense thank you! Looks like I have a lot of refactoring to do haha.